# How do I copy web clipping as Markdown?

Tags: gedit, html, markdown

I copy a HTML text, for instance, the first paragraph excepting from [Wikipedia: Dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set).

[image]

and then paste it to gedit. The expected results are:

```
In [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), a **dominating set** for a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) G = (V, E) is a [subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) D of V such that every vertex not in D is adjacent to at least one member of D. The **domination number** γ(G) is the number of vertices in a smallest dominating set for G.
```

I try [Copy as Markdown](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-as-markdown/fkeaekngjflipcockcnpobkpbbfbhmdn) which is only available for a single link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://markitdown.medusis.com/. This should give you the expected results.

Comment: It doesn't work perfectly. The bold texts are not rendered.

Comment: @SparkandShine Bold text is also rendered. This is the output I get for your sample text: 

`In [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), a **dominating set** for a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) _G_ = (_V_, _E_) is a [subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) _D_ of _V_ such that every vertex not in _D_ is adjacent to at least one member of _D_. The **domination number** γ(_G_) is the number of vertices in a smallest dominating set for _G_.`

Comment: which web browser do you use? Chrome doesn't work for me.

Comment: I am using chrome itself.